# Is it possible to get a LedgerTransaction object returned from the LedgerDSL in a Contract unit test?

Tags: corda

I have a unit test using this notation:

```
ledgerServices.ledger {
        transaction {
            ...
            this.verifies()
        }
}
```

I'd like to actually have the LedgerTransaction object so that I can test a helper method that takes in the tx as an argument. Is it possible to do this using the LedgerDSL or do I need to manually use the TransactionBuilder to create the LedgerTransaction instance in my unit test?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so.

I would suggest you compute a transaction and test your helper method as you test a flow:

```
    @Test
fun flowReturnsCorrectlyFormedPartiallySignedTransaction() {
    val lender = a.info.chooseIdentityAndCert().party
    val borrower = b.info.chooseIdentityAndCert().party
    val stx = issueIou(IOUState(10.POUNDS, lender, borrower))
    val inputIou = stx.tx.outputs.single().data as IOUState
    val flow = IOUTransferFlow(inputIou.linearId, c.info.chooseIdentityAndCert().party)
    val future = a.startFlow(flow)
    mockNetwork.runNetwork()
    val ptx = future.getOrThrow()
    // Check the transaction is well formed...
    // One output IOUState, one input state reference and a Transfer command with the right properties.
    assert(ptx.tx.inputs.size == 1)
    assert(ptx.tx.outputs.size == 1)
    assert(ptx.tx.inputs.single() == StateRef(stx.id, 0))
    println("Input state ref: ${ptx.tx.inputs.single()} == ${StateRef(stx.id, 0)}")
    val outputIou = ptx.tx.outputs.single().data as IOUState
    println("Output state: $outputIou")
    val command = ptx.tx.commands.single()
    assert(command.value == IOUContract.Commands.Transfer())
    ptx.verifySignaturesExcept(b.info.chooseIdentityAndCert().party.owningKey, c.info.chooseIdentityAndCert().party.owningKey,
            mockNetwork.defaultNotaryNode.info.legalIdentitiesAndCerts.first().owningKey)
}
```